# Set base directory for dynamic virtual hosts

Tags: php, security, ubuntu

I use Dynamic VirtualHosts for a hosting service I run. Currently, it only allows static sites, however I'm working on a new version which will support PHP. This clearly opens some security issues.

Currently, websites are stored in `/var/www/domains/{{domain.com}}`, and are configured using

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # this log format can be split per-virtual-host based on the first field
    # using the split-logfile utility.
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log vcommon
    ErrorDocument 404 /var/www/domains/hexagon.sudosu.co/templates/404.html
    # include the server name in the filenames used to satisfy requests
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/domains/%0
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to be able to set it so that the PHP base directory for each site is `/var/www/domains/{{domain.com}}/`, however other questions I've seen use `<Directory>` to set the PHP base directory and as my hosts are dynamic I cannot do this as far as I know.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, there isn't. (At least as far as I know.)

The apache design is based around a static configuration. The more favourable descriptions call [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html) a specialized case of mod_rewrite functionality instead of a hack, but the latter is a probably a better description.

None of the other Apache directives are dynamic.

You may be able to somewhat work around that limitation with an immutable `.htaccess` file in the root of each VirtualDocumentRoot directory and some measures to prohibit users uploading their own .htaccess files instead.